# How to read text not keys from property files with ResourceBundle

Tags: java, utf-8, internationalization, resourcebundle

I am facing a problem. The keys and values are fine to read with ResourceBundle from properties or text files but I have some i18n web page contents that are stored in properties/text file.

I want to display relevant language contents when website respective pages will be accessed. Is there any option in Java ResourceBundle to display whole file contents instead of display keys & values?

Please advise

Answer (score -1):

ResourceBundle is not really meant for that. Below is one simple approach using apache commons-io library. If you prefer a plain Java approach, you can use Scanner etc.

```
import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class DummyJunk {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        try{
            String s = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("/path/to/file"), UTF_8);
            System.out.println(s);
        }catch(IOException e ){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not the solution in my case. For example I have 3 files as `Disclaimer_en_US` , `Disclaimer_fa_IR` and `Disclaimer_ar_AE` then I have to add extra code as to which file should be displayed and more complex when we have to detect browser language.

Comment: That's not the purpose of ResourceBundle and you might run into issues. Resource bundle expects property and value and you even need to take care of escaping special characters. This also poses maintenance issues in future if the properties file somehow hosts the html content. I would instead suggest maintaining all these disclaimers as individual files and maintain a mapping of locale to file name in a properties file which will be read using ResourceBundle.

Comment: Can you provide an example what you said `I would instead suggest maintaining all these disclaimers as individual files and maintain a mapping of locale to file name in a properties file which will be read using ResourceBundle.`

Comment: Below would be the content of properties file which will be read using ResourceBundle and actual disclaimer files are read using File classes.

http://pastebin.com/CAhprTKF

Comment: This is not the way how ResourceBundle works. ResourceBundle select the files according to the Locale not keys and values according to the Locale. Again you provided wrong solution